# running jekyll locally on a github pages site project

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I want to create a project site documentation (not a blog).
I create a "project site" github page, as explained in https://pages.github.com, and select the theme 'jekyll-theme-cayman'.

However, when I edit the index.md file in github editor, the preview looks different from the output in my github page (produced by jekyll). I have only two files: `_config.yml` with the content:

```
theme: jekyll-theme-cayman
```

and `index.md` with the content:

```
# test
this url is not automatically auto-linked: http://example.com
```

I installed jekyll in my computer, but it fails as follows when trying to generate the output for my project site:

```
$ gem install jekyll bundler
$ bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: /private/tmp/test/_config.yml
jekyll 3.6.2 | Error:  The jekyll-theme-cayman theme could not be found.
```

How can I solve this?

Also, the text `http://example.com` is auto-linked by default in the github editor, but not in the jekyll output. I read [this documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/), and I tried with this `_config.yml` but it does not work:

```
theme: jekyll-theme-cayman
markdown: kramdown
kramdown:
  autolink: true
```

How can I auto-link?

also, the 'jekyll-theme-cayman' theme has a very tall header. how can I configure the theme? does this theme allow to change the header? where can I find the code of the theme and make changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the github-pages theme (it will prevent other problems and already contains the cayman theme), `Gemfile` should look like this:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "github-pages"
```

Then: `bundle install` and `bunle exec jekyll s`.

To customize the theme follow theme suggestion:

> If you'd like to change the theme's HTML layout:
>
> ```
> Copy the original template from the theme's repository
> (Pro-tip: click "raw" to make copying easier)
> Create a file called /_layouts/default.html in your site
> Paste the default layout content copied in the first step
> Customize the layout as you'd like
> ```

## autolinks

Autolinks in kramdown are meant to be surrounded by `<` and `>` like:

```
<http://example.com>

<https://example.com>
```

That would produce the HTML anchor link.

Comment: cool! I added the Gemfile (`source "https://rubygems.org" \n gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins`), and the repository attribute on _config.yml, and it works. I also found the repo you mention, with the code and documentation of the theme: https://github.com/pages-themes/cayman
last detail: what is the name of the markdown used by github pages? i tried adding `markdown: markdown` in _config.yml, but i still do not get auto-links if i don't wrap them in <> (as opposed to github pages, which does not need this wrapping)

Comment: Short answer: It [should be possible](https://github.github.com/gfm/#autolinks-extension-) but it [doesn't work](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/issues/306).